# Can sharepoint calendars have images and a legend with it?

Tags: sharepoint

Is it possible to add images to sharepoint calendar along with a legend of what each image represents? Below is an example of what its supposed to look like.

[image: Example image]

Is it possible to do something like this on sharepoint?

Please advise.

Thank you

I played around with the settings but couldnt find any options for this.